Iterative use of law of large numbers
Suppose we have random variables $X_1,X_2$ with means $\mu_1,\mu_2$. At each round $t$ we toss a fair coin and if heads we let $A_t=1$ and else $A_t=2$ and sample from $X_t\sim X_{A_t}$. I want to use the law of large numbers to show that if $N_i(n)$ is the number of times we sample from $X_i$ and $\tilde X_i(n)=\frac{1}{N_i(n)}\sum_{t=1}^nX_t\mathbb{I}\{A_t=i\}$. I want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}[|\tilde X_i(n)-\mu_i|<\delta]=1$. My idea was to first use the strong law of large numbers so I could omit histories in which we sample from one distribution finitely many times and then apply the weak law. But I don't know how to make this idea precise.

What does $t$ stand for in the definition of $\tilde X_i$? Did you forget to put a summation sign somewhere?

@framago yes! There should be a sum

The basic idea is that you flip a coin, sample from what the coin tells you, the observed means should approach the real mean.

I'm not sure to see your problem here. Would re-writing the sum as two sums (depending whether $A_t=1$ or $A_t=2$) seeing that one sum is empty and that the other is juste $N_i(n)$ times $X_i$ be enough?

@wece I edited my question.

Rather than LLN, you can do something using the law of total expectation.
Just for ease of notation, let $\delta_t = \mathbb{I}(A_t = 1)$, and let $N = \sum_{t = 1}^n \delta_t$. Also, to be just a smidgen more careful, I'm going to say that $X_{1t}$ is the draw from $X_1$ at round $t$.
Then if you just look at $\mathbb{E}(\sum X_{1t} \delta_t | N)$, i.e. the sum of the $X_1$ draws that are counted, conditional on getting a particular number $N$ heads, you can see that the sum is always going to be a sum of $N$ samples from $X_1$, so the overall expectation will clearly be $N \mu_1$ (you can formalise that argument a bit more if you want to).
So then applying LTE to $\tilde{X}_1$, we get
$$\begin{eqnarray} \mathbb{E}(\tilde{X}_1) & = & \mathbb{E}_N(\mathbb{E}(\tilde{X}_1 |N)) \\
& = & \mathbb{E}_N \left(\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum X_{1t} \delta_t | N \right) \right) \\
& = & \mathbb{E}_N \left(\mathbb{E} \frac{1}{N} \left( \sum X_{1t} \delta_t | N \right) \right) \\
& = & \mathbb{E}_N \left(\frac{1}{N} N \mu_1 \right) \\
& = & \mu_1
\end{eqnarray}$$

Than you for your answer but I had a problem in formulating my question. How could I get from this to answering my question in its current form?
